# Asp.net URL routing to third party link

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an Asp.net website and need to implement url alias functionality

http://myweb.net/sf --> should route to an outside url  say  www.sales.com

http://myweb.net/ts  --> should route to www.timesheet.com

Is there a way to implement this without creating Application (for each shortcut) in IIS ?

Solution using Web.config or database will be ideal.

Comment: How do you even expect to use ASP.NET without IIS? Also, what have you tried? This should be extremely simple and there is a lot of information online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description. I suggest that you could use URL rewrite to make the  url you entered  redirect to another. If you want route  http://myweb.net/sf  to www.sales.com and http://myweb.net/ts  to www.timesheet.com, you could directly add below in your web.config file:

```
    <system.webServer>
     <rewrite>
        <rules>
     <rule name="test1" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)/sf" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sales.com" redirectType="Found" />
                    </rule> 
 <rule name="test2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)/ts" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.timesheet.com" redirectType="Found" />

                </rule> 

        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: After installing URL Rewrite Module the above code worked like a charm. 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47337

Thanks Brando Zhang.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use rewrite in your `Web.Config` file

```
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.sales\.com$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sales.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

And same for  `www.timesheet.com` config file

> NOTE: this code is if you want to replace complete url `{HTTP_HOST}`,
>   you can do same changing `{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}` depending of conditional youre receiving, you set correct one

Comment: oops! I forgot to remove it from my code @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: I get your point. But for me, all I'm trying to create is basically shortcuts to other websites.

when user types  www.myweb.net/sf     it will take to sales.com 
when they type  www.myweb.net/ts  it will take to www.timesheet.com and so on..

Comment: So you can do it with code I provide you, just search in web, how to add new condition with your specifications... Remember `{R:1}` is the condition you want to modified so it should be inside conditions something like:   `<add input="{R:1}" pattern="^\sf$" negate="true" />`, just use your brain and do some test. I didn't test already because I don't have time, but that's the idea. @GaneshChandrasekaran